# Querying MongoDB documents using Java MongoDB driver 2.4

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to query a collection which has documents in the following format :

```
{
 "_id": "592be59e31c4fb0d04dba4f8",
 "CaseID": "XRTYET",
 "curdate": "2017-05-29",
 ....
 "env": "Mumbai",
 "description": null,
  ....
 "release": "0.0.1",
  ...
}
```

I try to search the collection for the existence of the following test fields using this :

```
this.mongoCollection.find(and(eq("CaseID", val.getCaseID()), eq("curDate", val.getCurDate()), eq("environment", val.getRelease())))
                        .projection(new Document("CaseID", 1).append("CurDate", 1).append("environment", 1).append("_id", 0))
                        .forEach(printBlock);
```

I also tried to count it but the output is 0. The syntax for count is :-

```
long count = this.mongoCollection.count(and(eq("CaseID", val.getCaseID()),
                                                eq("curDate", val.getCurDate()),
                                                eq("environment", val.getRelease())));
```

The count is 0 even though documents are present and I am unable to query the presence document on the basis of id or CaseID, curDate and environment.

Comment: Just at a guess, what does `val.getBuildDate()` return? I say this because I note that in your document the property you are trying to match is a "string". So I'm running with the idea that if you returned an actual `Date` type or a string with a different format, then this is not going to match. To which end you should really be storing as a `Date` type in MongoDB. Not only is it more useful like that, but it's actually using less bytes of storage than your "string" is.

Comment: Sorry for the typos

Comment: @Neil Lunn- The date field is stored as String. I will take your suggestion into consideration. Just started with it

Comment: It was a typo. getRelease should be getEnvironment